# Animating each data point (row) in R

Tags: r, animation

My data looks like following:

```
> dput(head(tht[,c(2,3,18,28)],15))
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), Frame.ID = 184:198, 
    Spacing = c(65.76, 65.26, 64.76, 64.26, 63.75, 63.23, 62.72, 
    62.3, 61.99, 61.72, 61.4, 61.02, 60.68, 60.42, 60.2), deltaV = c(3.13, 
    3.2, 3.26, 3.29, 3.3, 3.3, 3.27, 3.23, 3.18, 3.13, 3.07, 
    3.02, 2.96, 2.89, 2.83000000000001)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", 
"Frame.ID", "Spacing", "deltaV"), row.names = 3515:3529, class = "data.frame")
```

The complete plot of x= deltaV (difference in speeds between subject vehicle and leading vehicle) and y=Spacing (difference in distance) is shown below:

[image]

I want to animate it using `animation` package such that one data point is shown at a time and whole plot is drawn at the end of animation. I am not sure if this is the right package to do this. I tried following with no output (not even a static plot) without an error:

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)
## set some options first
oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.1, nmax = nrow(tht))
## use a loop to create images one by one
for (i in 1:ani.options("nmax")) {
  qplot(deltaV, Spacing,data=tht)
  ani.pause() ## pause for a while (’interval’)
}
## restore the options
ani.options(oopt)
```

Is the required kind of animation possible using this package?

Comment: Each new plot adds a dot?  so plot 2 has 2 dots?  Or each plot has one dot until the end and then the last plot is all the dots?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes, each new plot adds a dot. Plot 2 has 2 dots, then 3, 4,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)
## set some options first
oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.1)


FUN <- function() {
    lapply(1:nrow(tht), function(i) {
        print(ggplot(tht[1:i,, drop=FALSE], aes(y = Spacing, x = deltaV)) + 
            geom_point() + 
            xlim(c(min(tht$deltaV), max(tht$deltaV))) + 
            ylim(c(min(tht$Spacing), max(tht$Spacing))))
        animation::ani.pause()
    })
}


FUN()
```

I could explain how to think about setting this up but I think [THIS](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/animations-understood-5/) blog post on this does a 
good job and should give you a feel.  You can tear the code apart to check out how I did it.

```
type <- if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") shell else system
saveGIF(FUN(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd(), cmd.fun = type)
```

[image]